# Byte calculation of a class size

Tags: c++

What is `sizeof(salesman)`? It says 48 bytes and need explanation for why.

```
class customer {
  char c;
  double l;
  int k;
};

class salesman: private customer{
   int salno;
   char salname[20];
   protected :
    float salary;
 };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it's hard to second-guess a compiler.

But `customer` might reasonably require 1 + 7 + 8 + 4 + 4 = 20 bytes (the 7 and final 4 are padding). Then an additional 4 + 20 + 4 = 28 for the `salesman`, and it seems the compiler is smart enough to drop the final 4 bytes of padding from `customer` when doing the subclassing. That's 48!

The above assumes `sizeof (int)` and `sizeof (float)` to be 4, and `sizeof (double)` to be 8.

Comment: The interesting fact in this case would be that `sizeof(customer)` is 24, not 20, showing that the size of a complete type need not equal the size of a strict subobject of the same type.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev It's not the `char` which needs alignment, it's the `double` after the `char`.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev I meant the `double`, there's no need to align a `char`.

Comment: The sizeof (customer) is 24, as it requires padding and data memebers are not arranged with respect to size. So 1(char)+7(padding)+8(double)+4(int)+4 (padding) = 24 bytes.

Comment: @Uma Yes? If you agree with the answer, you're supposed to accept it, not repeat it in a comment. :)

Comment: @unwind, Uma's comment was explaining why sizeof(customer) == 24, while in your calculation of a derived class it only requires 20.

Comment: @unwind, I accept your answer. Perfect!! So  I need to consider that 8 bytes down the derived classes as well.

Comment: @Uma Okay. Accepting is an actual action, there should be a checkmark-like button next to my answer which you can click. I've edited to include the information that `sizeof (customer)` is 24.

Answer (score 1):

**Under the following assumptions:**

- The size of `char` is 1 byte
- The size of `int` is 4 bytes
- The size of `float` is 4 bytes
- The size of `double` is 8 bytes
- Padding is added, so that a variable of size N will **always** be located at an address divisible by N

**The memory map of a `salesman` instance is this:**

```
Byte   0   : char   c;
Bytes  8-15: double l;
Bytes 16-19: int    k;
Bytes 20-23: int    salno;
Bytes 24-43: char   salname[20];
Bytes 44-47: float  salary;
```

Hence the total size of a `salesman` instance is 48 bytes.

Please note, however, that the assumptions above aren't necessarily true on **every** compiler.

Comment: Agreed with the memory map, perfect.

Comment: I m not able to accept botj answers  as the other answers check changes to non green.

Comment: Cool, no problem then, just mark the one which you think answers your question in the most accurate way :) ... good luck ...